# Is there a way to reference the constructor of a type?

Tags: function, swift, constructor

In Swift you can reference a function, assign it a value, then use it later. We all know that. But I wonder if we can do that with initializers. Here is some example code. Suppose I have a `User` struct:

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let age: UInt

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        age = 0
    }
}
```

And I have an array of names

```
let names = ["Cooper", "Murph", "Brand", "Dr. Mann"]
```

And I want to map those names to `User` instances. I can do it like this:

```
let users = map(names, { User(name: $0) })
```

Although this seems good I feel using the closure that `map` function takes is unnecessary. I mean it basically takes a name and produces `User`. But we defined that in constructor of `User` struct. Why we need to repeat it? Is there a way to get constructor as function and pass it directly to the `map` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can’t reference `init` as a stand-alone function.  It’d be nice though.

You *can* access member functions like this:

```
extension User {
    func getName() -> String { return name }
}

// will be a function that takes a User object,
// and returns a new function that is getName
// called on that object:
let f = User.getName

let u = User("Fred")

// g will be a function that calls getName on u
let g = f(u)
g()  // returns "Fred"
```

If `User` were a class not a struct, you could also do this:

```
// h will be equivalent to g above...
let h = u.getName
h()  // returns "Fred"
```

Calling `init` feels like it ought to be more like the latter, since it creates fresh objects rather than taking existing objects.  `User.init` ought to return a function that takes a name and returns a `User` (though you have two initializers so you’d need to provide some type context).  But Swift won’t let you do that (tells you “Initializer cannot be referenced without arguments”).

One interesting thing though is protocols can require certain kinds of initializers, so you can do the following (fairly silly) thing to fake a function that initializes any type, provided for amusement only rather than practical use:

```
protocol StringInitializable {
    init(_ s: String)
}

// no implementation needed as User already conforms
extension User: StringInitializable { }

func initerFromString<T: StringInitializable>(s: String) -> T {
    return T(s)
}

let users: [User] = map(names, initerFromString)
```

The above fixes the type using the type of the `users` array, but you could do it by fixing the type of the function instead:

```
let userInit: String->User = initerFromString

let moreUsers = map(names, userInit)

struct Monster: StringInitializable {
    let name: String
    init(_ name: String) { self.name = name }
}

let monsterInit: String->Monster = initerFromString

let monsters = map(names, monsterInit)
```

(Somewhere this is actually used to actual practical effect is in `ExtensibleCollectionType`)

Comment: Is there a special reason that `initerFromString` returns a *closure*, instead of `func initerFromString<T: StringInitializable>(name: String) -> T { return T(name) }` and then `let users: [User] = map(names, initerFromString)` ?

Comment: Not really, just preference I guess (a generic function to produce concrete functions vs use of a generic function itself)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid repetition, you can skip giving named parameters by putting an underscore _ in front of the parameter.

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let age: UInt

    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
        age = 0
    }

    init(_ name: String, _ age : UInt) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

let names = ["Cooper", "Murph", "Brand", "Dr. Mann"]

let users = map(names, {User($0)})
```